# How to Turn page programmatically in UIPageViewController when the screen is off?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, swift4.2, swift5

I want Turn page programmatically in `UIPageViewController` when the screen is `OFF`. 
I try the following code

```
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([nextVC], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But this code only works if the device screen is `ON`. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Makes no sense. When the screen is off you cannot do anything. Your app is suspended.

Comment: when the device is locked and the screen is OFF setViewControllers method not work but if the device is locked and the screen is ON setViewControllers method work. So there is any way I can manage this when the device is locked and the screen is OFF?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use these functions in your AppDelegate :

`func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {}`

And :

`func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {}`

Then you can post a Notification that can be handled by your ViewController.

Comment: Thanks for the response but when the device is locked and the screen is OFF I want to continue the change page of UIPageViewController.